# override fosbundle RegistrationController symfony 3

Tags: controller, overriding, symfony, fosuserbundle

in first, i override fosuserbundle form it work but when try to do same thing with RegistrationController it does not work. Someone help please. 
I followed the documentation:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
   $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
   $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
$confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');
$process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();
.......
?>
```

> You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.registration.form". Did you mean one of these: "fos_user.registration.form.factory", "fos_user.registration.form.type"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to use the code of the `1.3.X` version. You should use the `master` version instead.
You can find it here : [RegistrationController-master](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php)

Or you can simply use the code found in `\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Controller\RegistrationController`

Comment: i'm using master version

Comment: Yes but the code you just wrote above is the 1.3.X version of the RegistrationController. So basically, you're trying to write the 1.3.X version of RegistrationController in order to override the master version of this controller, but this version doesn't use the same variable.

That is why you have a "non-existent service" error.

Copy paste the content of the master version of the controller into your own controller, and do your modification.